# Calculating distance in metres

Tags: postgis

Here is my code, the CRS is EPSG 4326:

```
 st_distance(
  st_transform(routes.points_geom, 4326)::geography ,
  st_transform(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326)::geography )
```

Am I correct in assuming that this will give distance in meters?

Comment: if your geometries are already in 4326 then there is no need to transform them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the [official documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html), we have the following:

> For geography types defaults to return the minimum geodesic **distance
> between two geographies in meters**, compute on the spheroid determined
> by the SRID. If use_spheroid is false, a faster spherical calculation
> is used.